# Pullback map of monotone map

Tags: category-theory, order-theory

I begun reading the “Applied Category Theory“ by Fong and Spivak, and I got stuck on this excercise (1.74):

> Let $P$ and $Q$ be preorders, and $f \colon P \rightarrow Q$ be a monotone map. Then we can define a monotone map $f^* \colon \mathsf{U}(Q) \rightarrow \mathsf{U}(P)$ sending an upper set $U \subseteq Q$ to the upper set $f^{-1}(U)\subseteq P$. We call this the *pullback along* $f$.
> Viewing upper sets as monotone maps to $\mathbb{B}$, the proposition can be understood in terms of composition. Indeed, show that $f^*$ is defined by taking $u \colon Q \rightarrow \mathbb{B}$ to $(f;u) \colon P \rightarrow \mathbb{B}$.

The solution states:

> Given an upper set $U\subseteq Q$, let $u \colon Q \rightarrow \mathbb{B}$ the corresponding monotone map, which sends $q \mapsto \mathtt{true}$ iff $q\in U$. Then $(f;u) \colon P \rightarrow B$ sends $p \mapsto \mathtt{true}$ iff $f(p) \in U$; it corresponds to the upper set $\{p\in P \mid f(p)\in U \}$ which is exactly $f^{-1}(U)$.

I don’t understand how $(f;u)$ can be $f^*$ if the former’s domain is $P$ while the latter’s is $\mathsf{U}(Q)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re misreading what the text is trying to say.
The map $f^*$ does not correspond to $(f;u)$, but to the mapping $u \mapsto (f;u)$.

Let’s be a bit more explicit than the text:

For any two preorders $P$ and $Q$ let us denote the set of monotone maps from $P$ to $Q$ by $\mathrm{Mon}(P, Q)$.
According to Proposition 1.73 (and its proof), we have for every preorder $P$ a one-to-one correspondence between monotone maps from $P$ to $$ and upper sets in $P$, given by
$$
  Φ_P
  \colon
  \mathrm{Mon}(P, ) \longrightarrow \mathsf{U}(P) \,,
  \quad
  u \longmapsto u^{-1}(\mathtt{true}) \,.
$$

Let now $P$ and $Q$ be two preorders and let $f \colon P \to Q$ be a monotone map.
We then have the induced pull-back map
$$
  f^*
  \colon
  \mathsf{U}(Q) \longrightarrow \mathsf{U}(P) \,,
  \quad
  U \longmapsto f^{-1}(U) \,,
$$
as explained in the question.
We can now consider the composite
$$
  \mathrm{Mon}(P, )
  \xrightarrow{\enspace Φ_P \enspace} \mathsf{U}(P)
  \xrightarrow{\enspace f^* \enspace} \mathsf{U}(Q)
  \xrightarrow{\enspace Φ_Q^{-1} \enspace} \mathrm{Mon}(Q, ) \,,
$$
which is a map from $\mathrm{Mon}(P, )$ to $\mathrm{Mon}(Q, )$.
The text claims that this map is given by $u \mapsto (f;u)$.

Graphically, the overall situation may be depicted as follows:
$$
  \require{AMScd}
  \begin{CD}
    \mathrm{Mon}(P, )
    @>{\enspace u \mapsto (f;u) \enspace}>> 
    \mathrm{Mon}(Q, )
    \\
    @V{Φ_P}VV
    @VV{Φ_Q}V
    \\
    \mathsf{U}(P)
    @>>{f^*}>
    \mathsf{U}(Q)
  \end{CD}
$$

Comment: So we are not looking for $f^*$, we're assuming it's already given to us? If that's the case then I think I got it. Thanks!